# .ephemeral says that dont exist in UNauthoritazionStatus

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, progressive-web-apps

When i try to built my app coming from PWABuilder in Xcode in IOS it says Type 'UNAuthorizationStatus' has no member 'ephemeral'I've checked Apple Guide and it says it exist. Im not an expert in IOS so i'm kind of lost right now

```
func handlePushPermission() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings () { settings in
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined:
                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            if success == true {
                                returnPermissionResult(isGranted: true)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                returnPermissionResult(isGranted: false)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            returnPermissionResult(isGranted: false)
                        }
                    }
                )
            case .denied:
                returnPermissionResult(isGranted: false)
//Error 1
            case .authorized, .ephemeral, .provisional:
                returnPermissionResult(isGranted: true)
            @unknown default:
                return;
            }
        }
}
func handlePushState() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings () { settings in
        switch settings.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            returnPermissionState(state: "notDetermined")
        case .denied:
            returnPermissionState(state: "denied")
        case .authorized:
            returnPermissionState(state: "authorized")
//Error 2
        case .ephemeral:
            returnPermissionState(state: "ephemeral")
        case .provisional:
            returnPermissionState(state: "provisional")
        @unknown default:
            returnPermissionState(state: "unknown")
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.ephemeral` is iOS 14+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationstatus/ephemeral What's your iOS target version ?

Comment: My XCODE simulators are IOS 13.3 that might be the problem, But what can i do if i want my app to be avaible IOS 14 or below